# GeoServer throws error when parsing thirdparty WFS `Unable to set property: boundedBy`

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I need to add an external WFS to my Geoserver, therefore I added a new Web *Feature Server (NG)* store with a name and pasted the GetCapabilities URL, the rest is the default (timeout 30s):

> https://geodienste.ch/db/planerischer_gewaesserschutz_0/deu?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Then I create a layer for one of the result layers and now I'm stuck with the following error:

```xml
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 https://.../geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
    <ows:ExceptionText>java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for FeatureCollection: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to set property: boundedBy for eobject: {http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0}FeatureCollectionType Parsing failed for FeatureCollection: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to set property: boundedBy for eobject: {http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0}FeatureCollectionType Unable to set property: boundedBy for eobject: {http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0}FeatureCollectionType class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class net.opengis.wfs20.EnvelopePropertyType (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader &apos;bootstrap&apos;; net.opengis.wfs20.EnvelopePropertyType is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @6a988392)</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

I also noticed that I get sometimes a timeout because QGIS does not request with a BBOX (another layer from the same GeoServer with a PostGIS database works)

QGIS Request for working layer:

> https://mygeoserver/geoserver/BE/wfs?SERVICE=WFS
> &REQUEST=GetFeature
> &VERSION=2.0.0
> &TYPENAMES=MyLayer
> &STARTINDEX=0
> &COUNT=1000000
> &SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2056
> &BBOX=2597983.16351239988580346,1196586.51665089884772897,2608657.04887334583327174,1198514.04788376484066248,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2056

QGIS Request for third-party Layer, that does not work:

> https://mygeoserver/geoserver/BE/wfs?SERVICE=WFS
> &REQUEST=GetFeature
> &VERSION=2.0.0
> &TYPENAMES=ms_gwszone
> &STARTINDEX=0
> &COUNT=1
> &SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2056

Did I miss a config I need to do?
or what could be the problem?

**Update**
GeoServer version: 2.18.0  (hosted in k8s/docker)
Other production GeoServer 2.13.2
QGIS: 3.20.0

**What I want to accomplish**
GeoDienste hosts data that we want to show to our users.
Unfortunatly the style of this Layer 'Grundwasserschutzzonen' [gwszone]
is not suitable for our use case, therefore we want to restyle this layer with a lighter style.

**What I did so far**
Now I added their WFS to our GeoServer:

- Created a new Workspace `GD`
- Created a new Store with the following settings:

  - WFS Capa URL:
    https://geodienste.ch/db/planerischer_gewaesserschutz_0/deu?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
  - Timeout: 30s
  - no username/password
  - default values
- Created an SLD style
- Created a layer `Grundwasserschutzzonen` from `ms_gwszone`
- Under Publishing I set the new style

In QGIS I added our GeoServer as a WFS source with version 1.1.0.

the same thing i tried in an older GeoServer [2.13.2] there it works without a problem.

Technically i do not need to relay this WFS, i want to serve this layer restyled as WMS, but as WMS i get only a transparent image. (will open another question about this)

Requests made by QGIS for GeoServer 2.18.0:

```
https://mygeoserver/geoserver/GD/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&TYPENAME=GD:ms_gwszone&MAXFEATURES=1&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2056
https://mygeoserver/geoserver/GD/ows?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.0
https://mygeoserver/geoserver/GD/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&VERSION=1.1.0&TYPENAME=GD:ms_gwszone
https://mygeoserver/geoserver/GD/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&TYPENAME=GD:ms_gwszone&MAXFEATURES=1&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2056
```

Requests made by QGIS for GeoServer 2.13.2:

```
https://mygeoserver/geoserver/GD/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&TYPENAME=GD:ms_gwszone&MAXFEATURES=1&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2056
https://mygeoserver/geoserver/GD/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.0
https://mygeoserver/geoserver/GD/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&VERSION=1.1.0&TYPENAME=GD:ms_gwszone
https://mygeoserver/geoserver/GD/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&TYPENAME=GD:ms_gwszone&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2056&BBOX=2674017.09097222937270999,1245006.68662121496163309,2676317.01672119600698352,1245950.04599621496163309,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2056
```

whats interessting on my home PC with QGIS 2.18.x it did make requests with BBOX

Error Messages/logs will follow, the Server is currenlty in use.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file. We'll also need to actual layer name that you are trying? But the first thing I would try is changing the version to 1.1.0

Comment: All three layers on that site work fine for me (after I turned up the timeout to 60s) - I'm using 2.19.2

Comment: @IanTurton sorry for not responding, changing to version 1.1.0 did work a little bit. I update the question with more infos

Comment: Note the actual URL for sending requests is `https://wfs.geodienste.ch/planerischer_gewaesserschutz_0/deu?`

Comment: `Technically i do not need to relay this WFS, i want to serve this layer restyled as WMS, but as WMS i get only a transparent image.` Issue to do with the original MapServer service for transparent image on WMS, may be due to scale layering

Comment: @nmtoken i have in both geoserver this: `https://geodienste.ch/db/planerischer_gewaesserschutz_0/deu?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities` but will try the other one.